# should I use strategy pattern, If I have hundreds of actions

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

I have a class doing translate job. But it have hundreds of specific translate methods! The action code determine which method will be used! I want to use strategy pattern, but it will create hundreds of sub class! I want to name the methods end of action code and use reflection to do the translate, but I'm concern abort the execution performances. It will be called very frequently! What design pattern or patterns should I use to solve this problem!
code like this:

```
public class Test003_Translate {

private static final String PREFIX = "translate";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Test003_Translate translate = new Test003_Translate();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key001", "001");
    map.put("key002", "002");
    map.put("key003", "003");
    translate.doTranslate(map, "key001");
}

private void doTranslate(Map<String, String> map, String key) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    String actionCode = map.get(key);
    Method method = Test003_Translate.class.getMethod(PREFIX + actionCode, String.class);
    String arg = "arg: ";
    Object s = method.invoke(this, arg);
}

public String translate001(String input){
    return input + "001";
}
public String translate002(String input){
    return input + "002";
}
public String translate003(String input){
    return input + "003";
}
}
```

Comment: Do not use reflection, anonymous classes, maybe with lambda, should be ok. But provide more details: how do you determine the actionCode?

Comment: I already know a map and a key, I can get the actionCode like this: map.get(key);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `EnumMap` (smaller and faster then a `HashMap`), like this:

```
enum Key {
    KEY_001,
    ....
}

EnumMap<Key, Runnable> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(Key.class);
enumMap.put(Key.KEY_001, YourClass::translate001);
....
```

And usage:

```
enumMap.get(someKey).run();
```

Comment: What if the method have parameters and returns, like this: 
`public String translate001(String input)`;
I don't want the translate class have any field to store the input, because the translate method will be called concurrently and we need this.

Comment: @liuliu "input parameters and return type" == `java.util.Function` instead of `Runnable`

Comment: thanks! does it proper to have a enormous class with about 4000 lines? But I do need these methods. We are translating hundreds fields from old system to new system, and they(the translate rule) have nothing in common!